# Why InSampleSize needs to be a power of 2?

Tags: android, image

I'm reading [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and I'm having hard time to understand the concept of `inSampleSize`

Why does it needs to be a power of 2? That generates an image bigger than necessary and I wonder why I just can't set the exact width and height.

Comment: You can use exact same size, but then it would still be the big Bitmap loaded into the memmory. First use insample size to reduce the bitmap itself, then set width and height to the required

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure probably they might be using coherent sampling to sample the image. which requires some of its parameter to be power of 2. Not sure though.